# Detect Changes In Two Or More CSVs Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, validation

I am trying to use Pandas to detect changes across two CSVs. I would like it ideally to highlight which UIDs have been changed.  I've attached an example of the ideal output [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbWUk.png)

CSV 1 (imported as DataFrame):

```
| UID      | Email           |
| -------- | --------------- |
| U01      | u01@email.com   |
| U02      | u02@email.com   |
| U03      | u03@email.com   |
| U04      | u04@email.com   |
```

CSV 2 (imported as DataFrame):

```
| UID      | Email           |
| -------- | --------------- |
| U01      | u01@email.com   |
| U02      | newemail@email.com   |
| U03      | u03@email.com   |
| U04      | newemail2@email.com  |
| U05      | u05@email.com   |
| U06      | u06@email.com   |
```

Over the two CSVs, U02 and U04 saw email changes, whereas U05 and U06 were new records entirely.

I have tried using the pandas compare function, and unfortunately it doesn't work because CSV2 has more records than CSV1.

I have since concatenated the UID and email field, like so, and then created a new field called "Unique" to show whether the concatenated value is a duplication as True or False (but doesn't show if it's a new record entirely)

```
df3['Concatenated'] = df3["UID"] +"~"+ df3["Email"]

df3['Unique'] = ~df3['Concatenated'].duplicated(keep=False)
```

This works to an extent, but it feels clunky, and I was wondering if anyone had a smarter way of doing this - especially when it comes into showing whether the record is new or not.

Comment: Please post example CSVs as text (preferably initializing dataframes we can use for test).

Comment: @tdelaney updated with a version of CSV 1 and 2 - is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy here is to merge the two dataframes on `UID`, then compare the email columns, and finally see if the new UIDs are in the UID list.

```
df_compare = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_new, how='outer', on='UID')

df_compare['Change Status'] = df_compare.apply(lambda x: 'No Change' if x.Email_x == x.Email_y else 'Change', axis=1)
df_compare.loc[~df_compare.UID.isin(df.UID),'Change Status'] = 'New Record'

df_compare = df_compare.drop(columns=['Email_x']).rename(columns={'Email_y': 'Email'})
```

gives `df_compare` as:

```
   UID                Email Change Status
0  U01        u01@email.com     No Change
1  U02   newemail@email.com        Change
2  U03        u03@email.com     No Change
3  U04  newemail2@email.com        Change
4  U05        u05@email.com    New Record
5  U06        u06@email.com    New Record
```